# Split a unicode string (Hebrew) by whitespace and find word counts

Tags: python, string, pandas, unicode

I have a data frame that contains a column "message". I want a new column "word_count", that will count all the words in the message. for example:

```
message: "Hello my name Hello"
word_count = {'Hello':2, 'my':1, 'name':1}
```

My actual data frame is in Hebrew, as Unicode.

I did this before with strings, but now I'm having issues with the unicode strings. I know I can't use the `split()` method, so I'm looking for another way to split a unicode string by white-space, and count each word.

My whole data frame is unicoded already. This is what I have tried:

```
def word_count(text):
    word_count = {}
    for word in text.encode('utf-8'):
        if word not in word_count:
            word_count[word] = 1
        else:
            word_count[word] += 1
    return word_count

..
history['word_count'] = history['clear_message'].apply(word_count)
```

I tried some more functions, but all of them returns the count in:

```
{u'': 1, u'\u05d0\u05e0\u05d0': 1, u'\u05e9\u05de\u05e2': 1}
```

Would love some guidance.

For example, input:

```
שמע אתה אחד הלא מובנים
```

output in word count:

```
{' ': 4, '\xa2': 1, '\xd7': 18, '\xa0': 1, '\xa9': 1, '\x9d': 1, '\xaa': 1, '\x91': 1, '\x90': 3, '\x93': 1, '\x95': 1, '\x94': 2, '\x97': 1, '\x99': 1, '\n': 1, '\x9c': 1, '\x9e': 2}
```

The expected output is like I wrote at the top (but in Hebrew).
My python version at the moment is 2.7.13, Probably should update.

Comment: Some sample data would help. Please print `df.head(10)` and your expected output.

Comment: If I knew the unicode sequences for your whitespace, I could use that to split. Pictures don't help me... I'll need text.. or at least some hebrew text. Can you help with that? Also, when you update, please ping me like this: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, so I see your update.

Comment: One last thing - please confirm your python version...

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ edited the question. Thanks

Comment: "I know I can't use the split()" I don't understand, why not? How are Hebrew words separated?

Comment: When I try str.split, I get `['שמע', 'אתה', 'אחד', 'הלא', 'מובנים']`, it works beautifully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this easily using `str.split` and `apply` with a `Counter` object.

```
from collections import Counter

df
            clear_message
0  שמע אתה אחד הלא מובנים

df.clear_message.str.split().apply(Counter) 

0    {'אחד': 1, 'מובנים': 1, 'שמע': 1, 'אתה': 1, 'ה...
Name: clear_message, dtype: object
```

Comment: I get: 
Counter({u'\u05d0\u05ea\u05d4': 1, u'\u05d4\u05dc\u05d0': 1, u'\u05de\u05d5\u05d1\u05e0\u05d9\u05dd': 1, u'\u05d0\u05d7\u05d3': 1, u'\u05e9\u05de\u05e2': 1})  
You know maybe what I should do?

Comment: @sheldonzy I could help if you told me what you wanted... this is what I get using python3.

Comment: Well it is working when I print it, but when I save it into the new column word_count, it becomes a mess again.
history['word_count'] = history.clear_message.str.split().apply(Counter)

by the way, what IDE you are using for data frames, etc.? I'm using Spyder but it's not that great.

Comment: @sheldonzy That's because the word counts inside the dictionary are being printed by the `__repr__`, which is different from what is shown in a `print`. But it works! That's the important part. Also, I use IPython and remove the terminal prompts for your convenience. It's not obvious but it's a lot of tedious work but no one can appreciate it because no one knows I do it.

Comment: Thanks, good to know. The thing is, I want to save all these dictionaries, for later usage.

Comment: Eventually it worked after i upgraded to python 3.6 (I had 2.7). As far as i understood, python 3 handles UTF-8 better than python 2. So I probably missed some casting before. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This works in both Python 2 and 3.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

input_val = " שמע שמע אתה אחד הלא מובנים"

def word_count(text):
    word_count = {}
    for word in text.split():
        if word not in word_count:
            word_count[word] = 1
        else:
            word_count[word] += 1
    return word_count

print(word_count(input_val))
```

Comment: Okay, but it has absolutely _nothing_ to do with pandas.